# Working with multiple users with X

Tags: ubuntu, x11, login

I have two users and need to switch context very often. Both of them uses some web browser, some terminal and misc. apps that can use graphical environment.

I could of course use login/logout but it's very annoying to open all needed applications again.
I thought about using different ttys, however couldn't achieve my result (I am on ubuntu) - `startx` runs some poor version of GUI. I tried to run `lightdm`, but it didn't work and it broke my already working session... why?

What is the best way to manage at once two logged users with their desktop and opened apps? And does running two such sections can have negative impact on performance (I guess both users apps would use RAM).

Comment: Switch to SDDM - it allows multiple user to use the PC simultaneously.

Comment: What next? I installed it, but running `sddm` or `sddm-greeter` on another tty returned an error.

Comment: No idea why it's broken for you or your distro. Works fine here. Maybe Google for the error or ask a new question. I'm not God, I can't know everything, I've no clue what you're running and what your error is. You're asking as if I owe something, WTF?